# Facebook OAuth login integration with app?

Tags: web-applications, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

My App is example.com and want to use facebook(FB) login for authentication/authorization. Per my finding on google, FB uses OAuth2 here.
I have one question here on the flow

1. First will register on FB with my webapplication and returning url as example.com. It will generate appId(public key) and appSecret(kind
   of private key)
2. Will display the facebook login dialog on my web application
3. User will provide the FB credentials
4. Once authentication is successful then FB displays another dialogue asking for permission
5. If user says yes, request will go to FB server and server send back the unique request token  and redirect the user to my
   www.example.com/redirectURL  .
6. Example.com connects with FB API with that request token and app secret
7. FB will generate the acces token and return it to example.com with user basic details like user_id,name/email_id etc

I am not sure if step 8 is correct ? If it is correct, then what is the use of access token ? Will it be used for further calls to FB in case any other 
user related details are required (provided user has given consent in step 5) ?